# Java8 ServiceLoader : Unable to load

Tags: java, groovy, java-8, serviceloader

In my Java8 Spring boot application that has a dependency on `groovy-json` library version 3.0.19 to execute groovy scripts, it fails with below exception when my application war file is deployed in Tomcat, but not in Docker or local development setup. On execution of script like `new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText('{}')` I see below exception:

'javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load FastStringService'

Above runtime exception is from this portion of code in groovy-json package: https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_3_0_19/subprojects/groovy-json/src/main/java/org/apache/groovy/json/internal/FastStringUtils.java#L35-L59

I've looked for conflicting dependencies, there is only this version of groovy-json library in my app. The particular class in question does actually exist in my artifact. Any ideas on this error?

**Updates:**

Stacktrace:

````
"org.flowable.common.engine.impl.scripting.FlowableScriptEvaluationException: groovy script evaluation failed: 'javax.script.ScriptException: org.flowable.common.engine.impl.scripting.FlowableScriptEvaluationException: groovy script evaluation failed: 'javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load FastStringService''",
  "  at org.flowable.common.engine.impl.scripting.ScriptingEngines.evaluate(ScriptingEngines.java:132)",

  "Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load FastStringService",
  "  at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:158)",
  "  at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:233)",
  "  at org.flowable.common.engine.impl.scripting.ScriptingEngines.evaluate(ScriptingEngines.java:111)",
  "  ... 152 more",
  "Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load FastStringService",
  "  at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320)",
  "  at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:155)",
  "  ... 154 more",
  "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load FastStringService",
  "  at org.apache.groovy.json.internal.FastStringUtils.getService(FastStringUtils.java:56)",
  "  at org.apache.groovy.json.internal.FastStringUtils.toCharArray(FastStringUtils.java:66)",
  "  at org.apache.groovy.json.internal.BaseJsonParser.parse(BaseJsonParser.java:113)",
  "  at groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parseText(JsonSlurper.java:204)",
  "  at groovy.json.JsonSlurper$parseText.call(Unknown Source)",
  "  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)",
  "  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)",
  "  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)",
  "  at Script449.run(Script449.groovy:2)",
  "  at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:317)",
  "  ... 155 more"```

Tomcat version: 9.0.71
````

Comment: do you have full stacktrace of the error? it should have caused by section with a reason... just a guess - tomcat is running on java 11+ when groovy version is quite old.

Comment: Updated with stacktrace partially. Java is 1.8.

Comment: If it runs standalone, then very likely something else tries to register this service and/or poisons the classloader. The error you are showing is the _result_ of that failure - but we need to know if there is a _reason_. E.g. what are the errors _before_, or what is the _full_ stacktrace. As of now, this looks like information is withheld.

Comment: @cfrick Added cause in stacktrace.

Comment: is groovy a part of your war?

Comment: groovy is not in file system, its fetched from my database. @daggett

Comment: sounds like you don't have groovy libraries in your application. or two conflicting versions of groovy inside tomcat/application...

Comment: Library is present in my war’s META-INF/lib folder just like all other deps. I checked dependency hierarchy from IDE and it doesnt show multiple versions. Adding jar explicitly in tomcat lib folder resolves issue, but not consistently.

Comment: What does "not consistently" mean? As in: it works, restart, does not
work?  This could mean, that there are clashing resources (e.g. multiple
jars with similar content) and you get random results from the class
loader.

Comment: Yeah on some restarts it works fine, but not in some. This is with adding lib in tomcat lib folder along with my application's lib.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the compiler finds it difficult to resolve dependencies when source code for java and groovy is in more than one source dir, so you can tell gradle/the compiler where to find the source to compile for the project by adding the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    groovy {
      srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/groovy']
    }
    resources {
      srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In this scenario, source code for groovy is passed dynamically. Not stored in file system.